# XML whit multi node to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

is there a way to map the import of an xml file into a dataset?
For example in my case I would like to import only "DatiAnagrafici" and add the "DataNascita" sub-nodes and "indirizzo" to the same table.

[xml tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuIRP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq the code would look something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Giorno", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Mese", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Anno", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Via", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Comune", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Provincia", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Cap", typeof(int));


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> datiAnagraficis = doc.Descendants("DatiAnagrafici").ToList();

            foreach(XElement datiAnagrafici in datiAnagraficis)
            {
                int giorno = (int)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Giorno").FirstOrDefault();
                int mese = (int)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Mese").FirstOrDefault();
                int anno = (int)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Anno").FirstOrDefault();
                string via = (string)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Via").FirstOrDefault();
                string comune = (string)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Comune").FirstOrDefault();
                string provincia = (string)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Provincia").FirstOrDefault();
                int cap = (int)datiAnagrafici.Descendants("Cap").FirstOrDefault();

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { giorno, mese, anno, via, comune, provincia, cap });

            }
        }
    }
 }
```